# MVVM Who Check Data Integrity

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-input

I'm working on my first MVVM app, and have noticed alot of my ViewModels include data checks such as

```
if( UserSalary == "this"){ MessageBox.Show("UserSalary is in incorrect format") }
else{ perform.thisAction(UserSalary); }
```

I image this is considered bad practice since this would mean my ViewModel is aware of the view.  I am wondering where do I check user input data integrity, in the View or View Model, and if the data is in incorrect format who is responsible for letting the user know, the View or the View Model?

Comment: It is not clear how you are separating your ViewModels (when working on MVVM I would have a separate project within the solution).  What does "this" refers to in your example code. Are you using data binding?, in which case you could do integrity checks in the setters?

Comment: The simplest solution is to implement IDataErrorInfo (and research how to set up your XAML to display errors). Check if you are valid before performing any actions. Let users enter invalid data, but tell them how to fix and don't act unless you're in an acceptable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify data integrity in both the view and view model, and what I've found is that the more lightweight data validation is typically done in the view (validation like verifying input string format) and heavier validation is done in the view model (validation like making sure the user can perform the given action, that the user name and password is correct, etc). The answer here is subjective.